# Android pattern for logout

Tags: android, logging

I'm curious if there is any framework pattern for logging out from application due to logout often works as clearing app and starting it as if it has been just installed.

**First**, Is there any shortcut for clearing whole app or you have to clear all persistent data like SharedPreferences, database, files manually ?

**Second**, is there any standardized Android logout pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** `Is there any shortcut for clearing whole app or you have to clear all persistent data like SharedPreferences, database, files manually ?`
**Answer:**

.clear() function can be used for clearing data.

For ex:

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // Make sure that you need to commit that.
```

**Second** `is there any standardized Android logout pattern ?`
**Answer:**

There's no need of that. You simply can use SharedPreferences for same.

Ex:

When you need to login then at that time simply save user login credentials in SharedPreferences file else when you need to log out then simply clear those values from that file.

That's it. you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to clear your sharedprefrences and files on click of signout button..